# Should I make purchases available to any user under the same apple id?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app is restoring purchases once the user logs in. Given that purchases are related to the apple id rather than my app custom user: should I make purchases available to any app user under the same apple id?
Is that how it usually works?

Comment: Please provide more information on the type of user your app custom user is.  For example, is it a game with a username?  This will help frame the question better.   Without background on the user type, it is hard to say what the best thing to do is.

Comment: It´s a fitness app. User login and paid subscriptions are needed to access specific stuff like statistics, cloud backup, etc. There are a number of IAP  for workout routines.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having the paid features tracked by your servers. Since you are providing a paid subscription service you want it to transcend the platform (Apple or Android). This way the user can move to Android or work with a laptop and not lose paid for features.  This also allows you to expand your service later.

If you tie the features to an Apple ID, then you are limiting yourself to Apple.  This might be easier in the short term, but in the long term you have made your life harder.

Comment: I´m afraid your answer is ignoring all kind of app store policies.